# C- Checking multiple number variables to be greater then 10 and move to the next

Tags: for-loop, variables, integer, modifier

I have **16** #'s labeled *num1, num2, etc.*  If any of these are above **10** I need to split the numbers into individuals. so 12 into 1 and 2. I have been modifying num1 = 12 into num1 = 1 and num1b = 2 successfully with the code below but I find it long-winded.

```
if(num1 >= 10);
   {
      num1b = num1 - 10;
      num1 = num1 / 10;
   }

if(num2 >= 10);
{ etc. and so on. }
```

I would like to have a for loop run through them 16 times and check num1 and if it's over 10 do it, if not skip it and move to the next num. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, not sure if it's a () or [] or what. I'm thinking `strlen` is going to come into play but I'm just not sure.

```
   for(int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
   {
      if(num[i] >= 10)
      {
        num[i]b = num[i] - 10;
        num[i] = num[i] / 10;
      }
   }
```

Ps: this is my 1st post ever so please excuse any horrid formatting issues, although I am open to criticism.

Comment: if there are 16 different variables, then you cannot simply iterate over them, you can iterate over array not variables

Comment: well crap, I haven't figured out arrays yet, I can use them if the values are given / programmable but I don't know how to take a bunch of variables that a user would input and put it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot `for loop` over variables, that's just not possible, unless they are contiguous in address but you surely will run into undefined behaviors if you did that.

that other way to do it is using `arrays` with `struct` as a placeholder.

the `struct` will act as a place holder which will contain grouped information about one item like :

```
typedef struct num{
    int units;
    int tenths;
}num;
```

here this will represent only one element in your array where `units` will serve as your digits between 0 and 9, and tenths will store any digits from 0 to 9 also. where 0 means that the number isn't splitted.

for the array, declaring :

```
num arr[16];
```

means that you create a contiguous place in memory of `size = 16`as it contains 16 elements. and the start of it is `arr[0]`.

so for reading 16 numbers from the user , you can try:

```
printf("enter 16 elements\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &dummyNumber);
    arr[i].tenths = dummyNumber / 10;
    arr[i].units = dummyNumber % 10;
}
```

where for every iteration, the number entered by the user is stored into a dummy number then store the tenths of the dummy number into the tenths of the `struct` of current position of the array.

and to print the result, you can try:

```
printf("result is\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    if(arr[i].tenths != 0)
        printf("arr[%d] = %d %d\n", i, arr[i].tenths, arr[i].units);
    else
        printf("arr[%d] = %d \n", i, arr[i].units);
}
```

where we get each element in the array and check if its tenths is 0 or not. if not then we print the tenths.

this is the full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct num{
    int units;
    int tenths;
}num;

int main()
{
    num arr[16];

    int dummyNumber;

    printf("enter 16 elements\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &dummyNumber);
        arr[i].tenths = dummyNumber / 10;
        arr[i].units = dummyNumber % 10;
    }

    printf("result is\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        if(arr[i].tenths != 0)
            printf("arr[%d] = %d %d\n", i, arr[i].tenths, arr[i].units);
        else
            printf("arr[%d] = %d \n", i, arr[i].units);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

and this is some example output:

```
enter 16 elements
12
5
3
20
14
2
3
6
4
2
55
2
33
12
41
12
result is
arr[0] = 1 2
arr[1] = 5
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 2 0
arr[4] = 1 4
arr[5] = 2
arr[6] = 3
arr[7] = 6
arr[8] = 4
arr[9] = 2
arr[10] = 5 5
arr[11] = 2
arr[12] = 3 3
arr[13] = 1 2
arr[14] = 4 1
arr[15] = 1 2
```